# Visualize Spatial Data in Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, geometry, spatial, reporting-services-map

Is it possibly to visualize a piece of geographical map from SQL server Spartial data (geometry, not geography) in a report from reporting service?

A concrete example is to display the orange line from the Chinese subway's map in a specific reporting page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Geometry can be surfaced in SSRS, but I havent seen anthing that complex.  Here's a starting point:

http://www.bimonkey.com/2012/07/the-geometry-data-type-and-ssrs-floorplan-reports/